# How to get the `comment_post_ID`?

Tags: plugin-development, comments, array, email, wp-insert-post

I have extracted the reply emails. The original emails are saved as CPT and work as Tickets in my plugin. I want the reply email to go as a comment to the original email.

```
 for($j = 1; $j <= $total; $j++){
            $mail = $emails->get($j);
//This checks if the email is reply or not and if the email is reply make it comment to its original post. 
    if ((!empty($mail['header']->references )) && ($mail['header']->references ) == ($mail['header']->message_id )
                {
                    $comment_array = array(
                        'comment_content' => $mail['body'],
                        'comment_post_ID' => ,

                    )
                    wp_insert_comment($comment_array);
                }
           }
```

I have distinguished the reply email and original email but I don't how to keep those emails as comments to the original email.
This is how my `wp_insert_post` looks like:

```
$post_array = array( 
            'post_content'  => $mail['body'],
            'post_title'    => $mail['header']->subject,
            'post_type'     => 'faqpress-tickets',
            'post_author'   =>  ucwords(strstr($mail['header']->fromaddress, '<',true)),
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'meta_input'    => array(   
                'User'      => ucwords(strstr($mail['header']->fromaddress, '<',true)),
                'From'      => preg_replace('~[<>]~', '', strstr($mail['header']->fromaddress, '<')),
                'Email'     => $mail['header']->Date,
                'ticket_id' => $mail['header']->message_id,   
            ),
        );
      //wp_insert_post( $post_array );
```

If anyone knows how to do it. It will be a great help.

Comment: "The original emails are saved as CPT" - is the post ID available in the `$mail['header']` (or somewhere in/via `$mail`)? Or when you created the CPT post, how did you reference the original email - is it via a post meta? If so, what's your code for saving the meta, or what is the meta key?

Comment: I am posting my `wp_insert_post` on answers please check it so you can get an idea.

Comment: I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you actually insert the comments right after you created the CPT post?

I.e. Both the snippets in the question are in the same scope, e.g. `wp_insert_post( $post_array ); for($j = 1; $j <= $total; $j++){ ... wp_insert_comment($comment_array); ... }`.

If yes, then you can store the post ID returned by [`wp_insert_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/) to a variable and then just use that variable with the `comment_post_ID` in your comment's arguments. E.g.

```php
$post_id = wp_insert_post( $post_array );
```

And then in the `$comment_array`, just use `'comment_post_ID' => $post_id`.

---

But if the snippets run in different PHP session/execution, and if the post meta named `ticket_id` is unique for each post in your CPT, then you can use the WordPress [meta query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters) and [`get_posts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/) to get the post that references the original email.

So for example,

```php
$posts = get_posts( array(
    'post_type'  => 'faqpress-tickets',
    'meta_key'   => 'ticket_id',
    'meta_value' => $mail['header']->message_id,
) );

if ( ! empty( $posts ) ) {
    $comment_array = array(
        'comment_content' => $mail['body'],
        'comment_post_ID' => $posts[0]->ID,
    );

    wp_insert_comment( $comment_array );
}
```

Comment: I did as you said now all the comments or replies are now being added to the first post.

Comment: Does the revised answer help?

Comment: No, It still is the same.
The `comment_post_ID` is not getting the ID it is supposed to have.

Comment: What's the full code you used? (show the entire code exactly as you put it in your file, including the part that inserts the comments) Can you post it on Pastebin.com?

Comment: I posted it on pastebin.com
https://pastebin.com/KfjmiFYj

Comment: The problem as I could see is that you run `get_posts()` out of your `for` block in the part that inserts the replies/comments. So try [this](https://pastebin.com/ABMiSU9Y) which is an exact copy-paste of your code, but see my notes on lines 46, 53 and 58.

Comment: Ok now, I see. But I'm another issue now. The reply messages are now inserted into comments but the same reply message is already inserted as a post as well. So, I can stop the reply message to go to post and only be added to the comments

Comment: That sounded like a generic PHP logic/programming issue, but even if not, you can post another question for that.

Comment: ok sure thank you!

Comment: I have posted a new question could you please see it.
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/400934/let-post-type-to-accept-only-original-mails-not-replies

Answer (score 0):

I maybe misunderstood, but you can create your comment thanks to https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_comment/ which will return you the comment_id on success.
In the parameters you can pass the post_id of the original mail in `comment_post_ID`

Comment: Yes, that's where I am getting the problem how do I get the post_id of the original mail.
There can be dozens of original mails and their replies. So, the replies should automatically go as comments to the original post.
That's the title of this question also suggests, how do I get the `comment_post_ID` ?